# Perceptron algorithm

Tags: classification, perceptron

I am trying to build a simple linear classifier. I have two classes A and B each with two features [x, y] and hence a 2d dataset. Now, I need to find the equation of the line that separates the two classes.

y = $\vec w \vec x - b$

I know exactly what $\vec w$ is. $\vec w$ is vector that is perpendicular to the line that separates the two classes, and b is the bias that shifts the line along $\vec w$. When b is 0, line is exactly at the origin.

I created the algorithm exactly as mentioned in this link.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perceptron#Learning_algorithm

But, in some cases it doesn't work properly. I've understood intuitively what the algorithm does. At each step, it takes a misclassified point, and tries to make correct classification by rotating the current line segment, and shifting it so that point is more closer to correct class.

I need an algorithm that helps me find $ \vec w $ and $ b $.

Here's my algorithm in ES6.

```
const learn = (target, learning_rate = .00001) => {
const { featureVector } = target;
// shift towards object
// const nm = math.norm(lineConfig.normal);
// lineConfig.normal = math.divide(lineConfig.normal, nm);
// lineConfig.bias /= nm;
const observedFeatureVector = featureVector.concat(1);
const wc = lineConfig.normal.concat(-lineConfig.bias);
const boundaryValue = math.dot(wc, observedFeatureVector);
const curOutput = boundaryValue >= 0 ? 1 : -1;
// lineConfig.bias += learning_rate * -target.cls;
// [w -b] [x, 1]
const dv = math.multiply(observedFeatureVector, learning_rate * (target.cls - curOutput));
const w = math.add(wc, dv);
lineConfig.bias = -w.pop();
lineConfig.normal = w;
```

};

I transform my input 2 dimensional data set into 3d by adding 1 [x 1] is our input vector. Then, all we need to do is to find $ \vec w $ only since bias is automatically adjusted. For every misclassification, I add the training point vector to the $ \vec w $ so that classification moves closer to the goal.

My training set is this:

```
[200, 200, 1]
[227, 347, 1]
[399, 237, 1]
[358, 344, 1]
[265, 263, 1]
[60, 20, -1]
[26, 100, -1]
[126, 95, -1]
[145, 58, -1]
[51, 141, -1]
[49, 186, -1]
```

Comment: you could add the source code of what you've already tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my implementation was correct but was taking too long to arrive at the solution because of the large range of input values. So, after I normalized using range normalization, the perceptron algorithm converged pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

> But, in some cases it doesn't work properly.

As you did not provide your data, I can only make a bold assumption.
The perceptron can only classify linear separably data and will not converge for not-linearly separable data. Thus, this could be a reason for the unintended behaviour.

Cheers!

Comment: I have 2d points that I draw. Each points' class is either 1 or -1. The points coordinates can have any range [-inf, inf], but they are also linearly classifiable. Now, I need to find the equation of the line that does that.

Comment: Also, I'd be happy to see a working implementation for any kind of 2d data.

Comment: I've added training set to the question.